# cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '__os_dispatch_queue_attr '

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

When I moved my code from XCode 8.0 to Xcode 9.4 . I am getting below error in my swift file

> cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type
>   '__os_dispatch_queue_attr '

Here is that line of code on which I am getting above error.

```
self.videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

Looking for helping answers.

Thanks

Comment: `dispatch_queue_create` is Swift 2. As of Swift 3 it needs to be `DispatchQueue`.

Comment: @Nirav, do google, u will find answer.

Comment: @rmaddy : can you please tell me how to do it ?